# when do you want to set up new environments in R

Tags: r

per the discussion of R programming styles, I saw someone once said he puts all his custom function into a new environment and attach it. I also remember R environment maybe used as a hash table. Is this good style? When do you want to put your data/functions into a new enviroment? Or just use the.GlobalEnv whatever?

**EDIT** put my second part of question back:
how to inspect same name variable for different environments?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Martin Mächler suggests that this is the *one* time you might want to consider `attach()`, although he suggested it in the context of attaching a `.Rdata` file to the search path but your Q is essentially the same thing.

The advantage is that you don't clutter the global environment with functions, that might get overwritten accidentally etc. Whilst I wouldn't go so far as to call this bad style, you might be better off sticking your custom functions into your own personal R package. Yes, this will incur a bit of overhead of setting up the package structure and providing some documentation to allow the package to be installed, but in the longer term this is a better solution. With tools like roxygen this process is getting easier to boot.

Personally, I haven't found a need for fiddling with environments in 10+ years of using R; well documented scripts that load, process and analyse data, cleaning up after themselves all the while have served me well thus far.

---

Another suggestion for the second part of your question (now deleted) is to use `with()` (following on from @Joshua's example):

```
> .myEnv <- new.env()
> .myEnv$a <- 2
> a <- 1
> str(a)
 num 1
> ls.str(.myEnv, a)
a :  num 2
> str(.myEnv$a)
 num 2
> with(.myEnv, a)
[1] 2
> a
[1] 1
```

Comment: Thanks Gavin. last time you helped me out on the R mutipart formula question. sorry for that question that I used 'answer' for 'comment' for unregistered userid.

Answer (score 6):

If your ecosystem of data and code has grown large enough that you are considering isolating it in an environment, you are better off creating a package.  A package gives you much more support for:

- Managing a project that is growing large and complex by separating code and data into files so there is less to dig through at one time.
- A package makes it dead simple to hand off your work to someone else so they can use your code and data.
- A package provides additional support for documentation and reporting.

Setting up a package for R is so easy, just call `package.skeleton()`, that every project I work on gets its code and data stored in a package.

The only time I use environments is when I need to isolate a run of some code, usually a script written by someone else, so that it's side effects and variable names don't get crossed with mine.  I do this by `evalq(source('someScript.R', local=TRUE), SomeEnvironment)`.

Comment: Why not use `sys.source` instead of `evalq(...)`?

Comment: Didn't know about `sys.source`.  At first glance it does not have a `local` argument which may allow variables from the parent environment to leak in and affect the run of the sourced script---which is what I am trying to avoid.

Answer (score 4):

To answer your second question (that you've now deleted), use `ls.str`, or just access the object in the environment with `$`:

```
.myEnv <- new.env()
.myEnv$a <- 2
a <- 1
str(a)
ls.str(.myEnv, a)
str(.myEnv$a)
```

Comment: thanks Joshua. This is what I wanted to know. I was just ashamed of asking basic questions and getting a RTFM answer so I deleted that part.