# R - evaluate nested function call in a deserialized environment

Tags: r, serialization, eval, environment

I am trying to run an *already existing* chunk of R code in a sandbox-ed fashion, by saving the global environment (containing functions and data) to a file, then loading it into a new environment (not the global environment) and evaluating a function call within that environment. However, I'm running into trouble with functions calling other functions in the environment. Here's an example:

```
f1 <- function(x) x*2
f2 <- function(y) f1(y) + 1
save(list=ls(), file="env.RData")
rm(list=ls())

jobenv <- new.env(parent=globalenv())
load("env.RData", envir=jobenv)
expr <- quote(f2(3))
eval(expr, envir=jobenv)
```

which fails:

```
Error in f2(3) : could not find function "f1"
```

whereas attaching the environment first works:

```
> attach(jobenv)
> eval(expr)
[1] 7
```

Is there a way to successfully evaluate a nested function call in the deserialized environment other than using `attach`?

(This question was forked from [R - Evaluate a nested function in an environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17732314/r-evaluate-a-nested-function-in-an-environment) based on commenter's suggestion)

Comment: I *think* `attach` *is* the [**right thing**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4412778/1478381) to do here...

Comment: `environment(f2) <- jobenv; eval(...)` will work but I'd not definitely recommend this way.